# Java and swift socket communication - confused about socket / stream implementation

Tags: swift, network-programming

I am trying to connect a swift client to a java server.

For the client, I have followed this tutorial here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/3437391-real-time-communication-with-streams-tutorial-for-ios

However, I am confused, because the client doesn't actually try connecting to the server untill it wants to write something.

Why is this hapening? Is there a way to make this conection happen without writing something?